# Amazon CloudFront Synchronization

Tags: synchronization, cache, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I want to leverage Amazon CloudFront to "cache" my webserver such that my website stays up even if my webserver goes down.  I understand CloudFront has many edge servers that facilitate the request/response process for site pages and associated files based upon a user’s location.

**Question**.  Will CloudFront synchronize *all* the edge servers automatically upon a page request that routes through a specific edge server?  Are there any associated limitations? (eg, will it typically take X seconds or milliseconds to sync all the edge servers?)

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=509557

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront will not suit this use case.

Each CloudFront datacenter caches files only when they're requested at that particular edge location. They do not proactively sync. Additionally, low traffic files will find themselves evicted from the cache to make room for higher traffic files.

You might consider CloudFlare's "Always Online" feature or something similar.